# Forgot small trips on travel history, tier 2 general

Tags: visas, uk

I'm a Brazilian researcher applying for a UK tier 2 general visa. I've finished and paid for my application and I'll provide documents and biometrics next week.

When filling out the form, on the section of travel history, I've entered only a one year trip I made to France for studies.

I forgot to add that I stayed in Portugal twice on overnight connections, both going in and out of France. I also forgot to add that I went to Italy to meet my girlfriend, who could not find a flight straight to my city (near the border with Italy) and flew in from there. We also returned to Italy later for tourism and stayed for a week.

Could I enter these trips in an additional document where I compile all my trips, along with boarding tickets, and explain my mistake was due to only focusing on big trips, and that I have no intention of withholding information from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explain the situation, and say that you were not planning to withhold information.

After submission changes can not be made online:

> If you have not yet submitted the application you can go back into the website, use your application number and amend the application. If you have already submitted the application to the VFS there is nothing you can do.

([Source](https://www.quora.com/I-made-a-mistake-in-the-application-form-for-UK-visa-What-should-I-do))

Alternatively, you can try getting in touch about your application [here](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk).

Comment: I have already submitted it, but have not yet turned in the documents or biometrics. Would a written letter be enough?

Comment: @GabrielMaia Yes it should, if my answer helped please accept it using the tick on the left. Thanks